# Allow language feature in Job Preferences

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, stack-overflow-jobs

I hope this is the right place to ask this:

Please can you add a **required** language section so that companies looking for developers in other countries can specify it and also the option for developers to filter the jobs shown based on this skill?

Right now, I live in Japan. Japan has five classifications of Japanese language ability for foreigners. These are called JLPT levels. These are:

```
JLPT1 Fluent
JLPT2 Business Level
JLPT3 Intermediate conversational
JLPT4 Conversational
JLPT5 Basic
```

I have applied for many jobs that when you get to the interview stage they then drop in they require the JLPT 3 certificate. It is a waste of time and effort.

Here is a quick Chrome developer tools mockup of how I envisage it for the development side:

[image]

Comment: This is a darn good idea. Honestly, it would be a *massive* improvement just to be able to specify languages in your user profile. I get plenty of emails from SO Jobs advertising positions where the entire ad is written in German or Japanese. I don't speak those languages, so these emails are entirely useless to me. I will never be applying to those jobs. SO should know that and trivially be able to filter these out. Adding the proficiency level is a cool idea, but much less necessary, and could be reserved as a future enhancement.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for this feedback. We plan to work on a feature around spoken languages in the future, and this is helpful information and context.